# How to Ping in Linux Shell from Windows

Tags: android, linux

I am new to Android development and I want to run PING command through LINUX shell. 
When I run PING in windows(example : 'ping google.com') it automatically calculates the max, min and avg time and displays it. But I am not sure if the same happens with Linux or not.
I have tried to ping using code, all I get is single line responses () and I am manually calculating the max, min & average times. So, I want to check directly by pinging in the LINUX shell and see if it displays the max, min and avg time , just like DOS does.

Any information would be helpful.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ping command with -c option.

just look like :

```
ping www.example.com -c <count>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.I am using the same in my code. But I want to enter it directly in Linux shell. In order to do this, I need to open the Linux shell first, may I know how to run this command in Linux shell on Win7?

Comment: Hi, finally traced it. I found out that running adb.exe (location: android-sdk->platform tools) through command prompt in windows. I typed in the following and it worked. syntax : adb shell ping -c 5 google.com